# How to consume WcfRequestProcessorClient?

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms, consumer

I need to consume a WCF service using the `WcfRequestProcessorClient` class.

How is the proper way using C#? Would it be possible do it with async/await?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use that class? Searching for that didn't seem like a standard WCF client. You can use WCF with Xamarin.Forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/ If the WCF generator doesn't give you async/await versions, then you can wrap it manually with Tasks in extension methods, then await those.